# Solid surface area

Tags: integration

I'm solving a question to evaluate a solid cylindrical surface area.

Consider a solid bounded by$ x\ge0 \, y \ge0 \, z \ge0 $, the sphere $ x^2 + y^2 +z^2=1$ and the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 -x=0$. Now i wrote the parametric representation of the cylinder as $\vec M$$[\phi,z]$=$\frac{1}{2} cos(\phi)$$\vec i$ + $\frac{1}{2}sin(\phi)$$\vec j$ +$z$$\vec k$. Now the surface area equals $\iint ||M_z$ x $ M_\phi||d\phi \ dz$ and since $ ||M_z$ x $ M_\phi||$ =$\frac{1}{2}$ then the integral is like $\frac{1}{2}$x$\iint dz d\phi$ now $z$ varies from 0 $\rightarrow$ $\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{4}}$ and $\phi$ from 0 $\rightarrow$ $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and so the surface area equals $\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{8}$, am i right doing so?  also shall i consider $x=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} cos(\phi)$ in the parametric representation?

Comment: You seem to have parametrized your cylinder as if its symmetry axis was the $\;z\,$ axis, whereas it is the line $\;\left(\frac12,0,z\right)\;$ ...